# flatMapping in scala/spark

Tags: scala, hashmap, apache-spark, flatmap

Looking for some assistance with a problem with how to to something in scala using spark.

I have:

```
type DistanceMap = HashMap[(VertexId,String), Int]
```

this forms part of my data in the form of an RDD of:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(DistanceMap, String)]
```

in short my dataset looks like this:

```
 ({(101,S)=3},piece_of_data_1)
 ({(101,S)=3},piece_of_data_2)
 ({(101,S)=1, (100,9)=2},piece_of_data_3)
```

What I want to do us flat map my distance map (which I can do) but at the same time for each flatmapped `DistanceMap` want to retain the associated string with that. So my resulting data would look like this:

```
({(101,S)=3},piece_of_data_1))<br>
({(101,S)=3},piece_of_data_2))<br>
({(101,S)=1},piece_of_data_3))<br>
({(109,S)=2},piece_of_data_3))<br>
```

As mentioned I can flatMap the first part using:

```
x.flatMap(x=>x._1).collect.foreach(println))
```

but am stuck on how I can retain the string from the second part of my original data.

Comment: Did you mean `({(100,9)=2},piece_of_data_3))` instead of the second `({(101,S)=1},piece_of_data_3))`

Comment: yes, sorry cut and paste error data i want should read: 

({(101,S)=3},piece_of_data_1)) 

({(101,S)=3},piece_of_data_2)) 

({(101,S)=1},piece_of_data_3)) 

({(109,S)=2},piece_of_data_3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
x.flatMap(x => x._1.map(y => (y,x._2)))
```

The idea is to convert from `(Seq(a,b,c),Value)` to `Seq( (a,Value), (b, Value), (c, Value))`.

This is the same in Scala, so here is a standalone simplified Scala example you can paste in Scala REPL:

```
Seq((Seq("a","b","c"), 34), (Seq("r","t"), 2)).flatMap( x => x._1.map(y => (y,x._2)))
```

This results in:

```
res0: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((a,34), (b,34), (c,34), (r,2), (t,2))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does it work for you? If it does I can write more, if not then there is no reason to spend more time here.

Comment: I did not try your solution since I was just reviewing answers, but your edit seems to have raised the quality of your answer. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

## update

I have an alternative solution - flip key with value and use flatMapValues transformation, and then flip key with value again: see pseudo code:

```
x.map(x=>x._2, x._1).flatMapValues(x=>x).map(x=>x._2, x._1)
```

## previous version

I propose to add one preprocessing step (sorry I have no computer with scala interpreter in front of me till tomorrow to come up with working code).

1. transform the pair rdd from `(DistanceMap, String)` into the rdd with list of Tuple4: `List((VertexId,String, Int, String), ... ())`
2. apply flatMap on on result

Pseudocode:

```
rdd.map( (DistanceMap, String) =>  List((VertexId,String, Int, String), ... ()))
    .flatMap(x=>x)
```